# Mask blank values using numpy.ma

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having trouble getting `numpy.ma` to work with my data. I'm sure I've used it before to mask blank values but can't figure out how. Here's a snippet of code that shows the problem I'm having.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

x = np.array([[0.0, 1.1, '', 2.2, ''],[3.3,'', 4.4, '', 5.5]])
for index, value in np.ndenumerate(x):
    if value == '':
        x[index] = None
x = ma.masked_values(x, None)
print x
```

This prints:

```
[['0' '1' 'N' '2' 'N']
 ['3' 'N' '4' 'N' '5']]
```

What I'm trying to do is get a masked array of floats with any missing values masked out. The final `print` should produce:

```
[[0.0 1.0 -- 2.0 --]
 [3.0 -- 4.0 -- 5.0]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replaced empty strings with `NaN`, the following would work:

```
In [19]: x = np.array([[0.0, 1.1, np.nan, 2.2, np.nan],[3.3,np.nan, 4.4, np.nan, 5.5]])

In [20]: m = ma.masked_array(x, np.isnan(x))

In [21]: print(m)
[[0.0 1.1 -- 2.2 --]
 [3.3 -- 4.4 -- 5.5]]
```

The easiest place to change the `''` to `np.nan` is before you place them in `np.array`.